# Visual Basic.NET Saving Preferences in a .txt or .ini

Tags: vb.net, preferences

I want to save my preferences for a program. I just want to know how to do it, since I cant get how to save this file at my documents, because every computer has a different name and username, but using the

```
My.User.Name
```

returns 'USERNAME-PC-USERNAME' which doesn't work.

For example, I want the program to create this text file 'CPreferences' at 'C:\Users\'username'\Documents'. And then when the program is re-opened it will automatically load this file into itself, the file will basically contain 2 lines:

```
Option1:<Value 1>
Option2:<Value 2>
```

The values will represent choices, ofcourse. So fundamentally, my question is:

1) How to save this file automatically at this user's documents WITHOUT showing a savefiledialog?
2) How to automatically load it if the file there exists?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is user configuration.

You can store settings for users that will be unique to the logged in user.

Use this as a reference for getting started with it:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12252/Application-settings-in-VB-NET-2-0-and-Visual-Stud

Answer (score 3):

VB.Net has [built-in features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for storing and retrieving the user's settings. Just use them. You won't have to worry about how the settings are stored or where the files are. It all just works.

Answer (score 2):

Using something along the lines of `string = "----------- " & CurrentTitle & " (" & Now.ToString() & ") User " & Environment.UserName & " on computer " & Environment.UserDomainName & "------------"`

will result in

`----------- Google - Google Chrome (3/12/2012 2:09:49 AM) User Drise on computer Drise-LAPTOP ------------`

Using a streamwriter with filename `"C:\users\" & Environment.UserName & "..."` should do the trick.

To auto-load the file, check if [the file exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) and use a streamreader with the same path variable as above, or if not, then set default settings.

Answer (score 2):

For saving to the "My Documents" folder for the current user, this will return the directory path:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
```

You can also use other items in "special directories" if you want things like the "downloads" or "my pictures" folders, or anything else like that.